# How do I make circular hitboxes that change?

Tags: java, integer, processing, mouseclick-event

Im new to programming and I'm making a aim trainer game where you hit different circles and have to hit one before it changes to the next circle. I having some trouble though. I can't figure out how to make a hitbox for the circles that change for each circle and how to increase the score.

The code is in open processing in pjs.

```
  class Timer {
  int time;
  int duration;
  Timer() {
    duration = 100;
    reset();
  }
  void reset() {
    time = millis() + duration;
  }
  boolean alarm() {
    if ( millis() > time ) {
      time = millis() + duration;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}


float x,y,s; //size and position of circles
color c; //colour of circles
int score = 0; //score
int miss = 0; //misses

Timer timer = new Timer();

void setup() {
  size(700, 500);
  timer.duration = 2000; //changes the circle every 2 seconds
    missed =+ 1;
  newEllipse(); // Make initial circle.
}

void draw() {
  background(100);
  fill(c);
    text("SCORE: " + str(score),620,20);
    text("MISSED: " + str(miss),20,20);
  ellipse(x, y, s, s);
  if( timer.alarm() ){
    newEllipse();
  }
}

void mousePressed(){
  if( overEllipse() ){
        score =+1;
    newEllipse();
  }
}

boolean overEllipse(){
    if(mouseX > x && mouseX < x+s && mouseY > y && mouseY < y + s);
}

void newEllipse() {
  s = random(5,min(50,50));
  x = random(0, width - s);
  y = random(0, height - s);  
  c = color( random(255), random(255), random(255) );
  timer.reset();
}
```

Comment: Are you willing to use OOP? You can create many objects which will have their own coordinates, thus making it easier to have several of them at the same time or to "chain" some when you want to be forced to hit them one after the other.

Comment: I would be willing to use "OOP" but I have no idea how to do that. I just started programming a couple weeks ago.

Comment: Object Oriented Programming is great, once you unlock it's potential you'll ascend to another level of development! If nobody jumps in here I'll give you a hand as soon as possible.

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Comment: This question also doesn't seem like a very good fit for SO - we usually help with technical issues which you haven't manage to resolve on your own, as opposed to helping new developers. Keep this in mind and good luck with OOP!

Answer (score 0):

Once I tried your code I realized that you were going for something very simple, so no need for OOP today. I fixed and commented your code so you can tweak it and test stuff:

```
float s; //size of circles
PVector targetPosition; // position of target
color c; //colour of circles
int score = 0; //score
int miss = 0; //misses

Timer timer = new Timer();

void setup() {
  size(700, 500);
  timer.duration = 2000; //changes the circle every 2 seconds
  newEllipse(); // Make initial circle.
}

void draw() {
  background(100);
  fill(255);  // easier to read if you don't change the color all the time
  text("SCORE: " + str(score), 620, 20);
  text("MISSED: " + str(miss), 20, 20);

  fill(c);
  ellipse(targetPosition.x, targetPosition.y, s, s);
  if ( timer.alarm() ) {
    miss += 1; // added a 'miss' when the user isn't able to click the target in due time
    newEllipse();
  }
}

// notice that I switched this method for 'mouseClicked' instead of 'mousePressed'
// the difference is that this works on a simple click, and run once per click instead of continuously
void mouseClicked() {  
  if (overEllipse()) {
    score += 1;
    newEllipse();
  } else { // added a 'miss' when the user clicks at random
    miss += 1;
  }
}

boolean overEllipse() {
  // these 3 lines are giving you feedback so you know how close to the target you were
  PVector mousePosition = new PVector(mouseX, mouseY);
  println(mousePosition.dist(targetPosition) + " / " + s/2);

  // you only need the next line if you don't care about the feedback
  return mousePosition.dist(targetPosition) < s/2;
}

void newEllipse() {
  s = random(10, 50); // I removed the `min(50,50)` because the minimum number between 50 and 50 is... 50. Maybe you were going for something else, but like this it was not needed
  targetPosition = new PVector(random(s/2, width - s/2), random(s/2, height - s/2));
  c = color( random(255), random(255), random(255) );
  timer.reset();
}

class Timer {
  int time;
  int duration;
  
  Timer() {
    duration = 100;
    reset();
  }
  
  void reset() {
    time = millis() + duration;
  }

  boolean alarm() {
    if ( millis() > time ) {
      time = millis() + duration;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

The main problem here was that the method `overEllipse` made no sense, so I set it on fire and rewrote it using a `PVector` instead of straight coordinates. I did it mostly because it's easier than to use math to determine if we're clicking inside the target later (the `PVector` class will straight up do it for you, it's an awesome tool, take a look at how I tweaked the `overEllipse` method and how it's easy with this tool!). I also added some feedback as console `println` so you can know how close you clicked from the target.

I'll be around of there's something you'd like me to explain. Have fun!

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps me alot and you also put comments to help me understand!